# Using regex to remove characters till the last -

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm new to regex and trying to figure out how to remove characters till the last - in the string. I currently have strings in the format like this:

```
purple-hoodie.jpg-1625739747918
```

I am trying to remove characters to essentially be left with:

```
-1625739747918
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to approach this? I'm struggling to work out how to indicate to reach the last - in the string, if that is even possible?

Thanks

Comment: not a react issue

Comment: if you found answer to your question, please dont forget to accept it (green tick)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

```js
let str = 'purple-hoodie.jpg-1625739747918'
console.log(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('-')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a `match` approach here:

```js
var input = "purple-hoodie.jpg-1625739747918";
var output = input.match(/-\d+$/)[0];
console.log("match is: " + output);
```

But this assumes that the input would end in all digits.  A more general regex approach might use a replace all:

```js
var input = "purple-hoodie.jpg-1625739747918";
var output = input.replace(/^.*(?=-)/, "");
console.log("match is: " + output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
const txt = 'purple-hoodie.jpg-1625739747918';
const result = txt.replace(/-\d+$/, '');
console.log(result)
```

This removes the last trailing digits prefixed by -.

Comment: This removes the very content the OP wants to match, leaving behind what is not wanted.

Comment: @Tim Please take an example